# Is this weird glob of brownish stuff a fungus?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, fungus

I was doing my daily inspection of my plants I noticed this weird glob of stuff in the pot of one of my trees. I'm trying to figure out what exactly this is, because I've seen the same thing in another pot about a month ago. Is this some kind of fungus?

[image: weird stuff in pot]

Comment: Easter bunny droppings?

Comment: LOL that's a good one. :) 

If it's a mushroom it's super weird looking. But I guess that makes sense. Both times it occurred it grows just on top of the mulch in the pot and it seem to grow just overnight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bark mulch leads me to think it's a slime mold - which is either a fungus or Something Else, depending on who you listen to.  See, for instance, [this article](http://planttalk.colostate.edu/topics/insects-diseases/1435-slime-mold/) from the Colorado Extension Service.  Beyond ugliness, it's harmless.

Comment: Oh wow! I think that's it! Great article. Thanks! :)

Comment: The link to the article is a dead link.

Comment: I took the liberty to replace the link.